# java.lang.AbstractMethodError in Firebase Android (FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.readGenerateAuthTokenResponse)

Tags: java, android, firebase

We have this crash that in Play Console has occurred some 1.1million times and counting, with no success figuring out why.

The report:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
  at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.readGenerateAuthTokenResponse (FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:569)
  at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.generateAuthToken (FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:421)
  at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.fetchAuthTokenFromServer (FirebaseInstallations.java:566)
  at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary (FirebaseInstallations.java:390)
  at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2 (FirebaseInstallations.java:377)
  at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.$r8$lambda$VZq1h0TBcWNH8Y5yY86ujrFFyLo (FirebaseInstallations.java)
  at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$8f6250a76dc84afdee54bd79d6c6b27858a3db00ee2f9ff4dae9d6825fe4cbe4$0.run$bridge (FirebaseInstallations.java:18)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
```

There's little more we have to work with...it is seemingly entirely contained in the Firebase SDK.

The crash is not reproducible by anyone on team and none of the pre-launch test devices exhibit any issue or any mass device testing service. Firebase Messaging appears to be working fine in any manner we can test.

We were on

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.x.x
```

So we updated to

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0
```

Nothing changed, the crash is still pouring in every hour.

One prior update to that we removed permission: android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION to be compliant with that recent change. However it was a relic and the app has not actually required it for years.

This is seemingly when the crash began, though as far as I'm aware, Firebase SDK doesn't need this permission and hasn't needed it but we're grasping at straws.

Some build vars:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 30
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion 32.0.0
Gradle 7.1.2

android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
android.enableR8.fullMode=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

It feels like a build problem, as our code base changed *very* little (a single manifest perm line before attempting the Firebase SDK update)...but we're just not having much luck and the variance in not every one encountering it, is peculiar.

Answer (score 5):

In the event this helps a single person avoid the pain we endured. Our solution was adding this to proguard:

```
-keepattributes AutoValue

-keep class com.google.firebase.installations.** {
  *;
}

-keep interface com.google.firebase.installations.** {
  *;
}
```

And changing our depend to:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

We are not entirely clear on why this became necessary.

Comment: did you end up sticking with this solution ? I've been seeing similar crash logs in Firebase crashlytics on a Flutter app. Seems to happen at fb init when it makes some network calls. Proguard approach didn't work for us.

Comment: I reported this to [Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244700433) now let's wait.

Comment: The above mentioned solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Firebase Installations Service.

Thank you Niklas, for reporting this crash in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244700433.

As you mention in the ticket, this crash will happen if the android proguard rules weren't loaded properly.

If one runs into this crash, please double check that `proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"))` is present in app's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: We have been using `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` and this crash has suddenly appeared in the past 24 hours. Do we also need to add the ProGuard rules posted above by @RandomIO?