# Error occured after upgrading Firebase from 11.4.0 to 14.4.0

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase

I have upgraded all packages and it shows this error on some devices. What I am doing wrong? Can anyone explain what is the problem there?

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "androidx.appcompat.view.menu.c androidx.appcompat.view.menu.c.D (int)" at p2.e.h(FirebaseinstallationServiceClient java:90) at p2.e.b(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:98)
at
com.google. firebase.installations.e.f(FirebaseInstallation s.java:31)
at com.google.firebase.installations.e.c(FirebaseInstallation s.java:68)
at m2.d.run(Unknown Source:4)
at b2.f.run(SequentialExecutor java:3) at b2.g.a(SequentialExecutor java:85) at b2.g.run(SequentialExecutor. java:1)
at
java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor.run Worker(Threa dPoolExecutor.java:1137) at java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Thre adPoolExecutor java:637) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.b.a(CustomThreadFacto ryjava:13) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.a.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.lang. Thread.run(Thread java:1012)
```

Old version of app was released 6 months ago, now I am trying to upgrade all packages. But there is something wrong with firebase

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/71346505/7874746

Comment: May be you also need to upgrade gradle Android packages according to current firebase requirements.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved thanks, now I'm not facing this issue.